# Replacing a word in an output. php

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

```html
<?php
 $file = 'C:\wamp\www\Killboard\EPChernarus1\PhitLog.txt';
 $searchfor = 'Chernarus';
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
 $contents = str_replace("(ArmA-AH.net)", "(DayZNorway.com)", $contents);
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
 $contents = str_replace("DayZ Instance: 11", " Map: Chernarus ", $contents);
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*$/m";
 $contents = str_replace("PKILL", "Player Killed", $contents);
 $contents = str_replace("CLOG", "Combat Logged", $contents);

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
 echo "<strong>";
    echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#2983CB'>Killboard Epoch Chernarus: <br>";
 echo '', implode(" <br>", $matches[0]);
 echo "</strong>";
    }
else 
 {
 echo "No kills yet. Looks like everyone is playing nice.";
    }
 ?>
```

After much help on here, code now looks this ^
Now i am trying to include the code below.
So that it will rename the weapon classes to more userfriendly names.
I have included the two .php files its looking for, but i am unsure to where i place it and if it will even run like it is, wich i doubt.

Could someone

```html
  if ($line_type == 'kill') {
   include("killfeed_weapon_classnames.php");
   include("killfeed_weapon_cleannames.php");
   $swap_key = array_search($line_varlist['weapon'], $wcn);
   if($swap_key != false) { $line_varlist['weapon'] = $wn[$swap_key]; }
  }
```

Comment: Side-note: I am unable to change the way it is logged into the PhitLog.txt file

Comment: Have you tried to use a replace regex?

Comment: `str_replace`, simply.

Comment: Havent tried a replace regex no, could you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Before all of your preg matching and right after $contents use:

```
$contents = str_replace("(Arma-AH.net)", "(DayZNorway.com)", $contents);
```

Edited forgot the parenthesis and next question. I am not going to just give you the next part, but look at the example below and follow along this should help you achieve what you want for that next question.

```
$myArray = array("firstName" =>"sam", "secondName" => "billy", "thirdName" => "sally");


$nameKey = array_search("billy", $myArray);

echo $nameKey;

if($nameKey){
    $myArray[$nameKey] = "Tom";
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: Edited I forgot the parenthesis. If this still isn't working just put it in the loop on the matches right before the output. So on the line before your implode matches. Do it on matches[0]

Comment: Nope still didnt work. Could you show me exactly what you mean? i might be doing it wrong

Comment: Would also be awesome if it was possible to display the output by the newest at the top. The outputted text is all dated, is that doable?

Comment: For doing that you will need to regex each of the pieces out, and store the dates into datetime objects and use a date comparison function. To sort them.  I still don't know why my answer doesn't work for the original question. If it doesn't work then that piece of text is not in the text file you are pulling in.

Comment: It did work! I did something wrong, so all good now. But for the sorting after date. Is that a big task or could you possibly help me out here aswell? Much appreciated!

Comment: And finally, what if i have multiple words that i need to replace but with different words? For example i want to replace the arma-ah.net to dayznorway.com and i also want to replace pkill with player killed?

Comment: Just run str replace again if they are not near each other. and change out the words.

Comment: Edited first post for my final question!

Comment: @KimDavidSkråmestøEide udated answer to contain how to achieve final question

Comment: if ($line_type == 'kill') {
   include("killfeed_weapon_classnames.php");
   include("killfeed_weapon_cleannames.php");
   $swap_key = array_search($line_varlist['weapon'], $wcn);
   if($swap_key != false) { $line_varlist['weapon'] = $wn[$swap_key]; }
  }   ^ This was the code snippet i was referring to. I figured out the multiple ones already ;) Thanks alot tho! ;D'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file = 'C:\wamp\www\Killboard\EPChernarus1\PhitLog.txt';
    $searchfor = 'Chernarus';
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $contents = str_replace("(ArmA-AH.net)", "(DayZNorway.com)", $contents);
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $contents = str_replace("DayZ Instance: 11", " Map: Chernarus ", $contents);
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*$/m";
    $contents = str_replace("PKILL", "Player Killed", $contents);
    $contents = str_replace("CLOG", "Combat Logged", $contents);

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo "<strong>";
    echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#2983CB'>Killboard Epoch Chernarus: <br>";
    echo '', implode(" <br>", $matches[0]);
    echo "</strong>";
    }
else 
    {
    echo "No kills yet. Looks like everyone is playing nice.";
    }
 ?>
```

This is what i ended up doing, now its hardly pretty, but it works.
Now i need to get the results to show in descending order.

Any chance someone could help me with this?